# Android Paint.breakText doesn't work on KitKat

Tags: android, text, ligature

For the string like *"View profile"* `Android`'s `Paint.breakText` (on KitKat) returns 11 characters instead of 12.

```
numberofchars = MyPaint.breakText ("View profile", // String text, 
           true, //     boolean measureForwards, 
           8192, //     float maxWidth, 
           null) //     float[] measuredWidth)
```

It must return 12 chars in `numberofchars`, not 11. It looks like it's because of the *"fi"* in *"View profile"*.

Comment: count starts from 0 so that

Comment: no it's not this :(

Comment: Correct, `fi` is treated as a ligature. Here is the [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63281).

I ended up writing a custom "text breaker".